# Django on Google App Engine: "Instance names cannot contain the ':' character."

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) to run a Django project on Google AppEngine. I have reached the steps to create a Cloud SQL instance. I am on this step:

> Now use the Cloud SDK from command line to run the following command. Copy the value shown for connectionName for the next step.
>
> gcloud sql instances describe [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]
>
> The connectionName value is in the format [PROJECT_NAME]:[REGION_NAME]:[INSTANCE_NAME].

I get the following error:

```
$ gcloud sql instances describe django-polls-184415:us-west1:polls
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) Instance names cannot contain the ':' character. If you meant to indicate the
project for [polls], use only 'polls' for the argument, and either add
'--project django-polls-184415:us-west1' to the command line or first run
  $ gcloud config set project django-polls-184415:us-west1
```

When I follow the instructions in the error message, I get

```
$ gcloud config set project django-polls-184415:us-west1          
Updated property [core/project].
$ gcloud sql instances describe polls                             
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.
$ gcloud sql instances describe --project django-polls-184415:us-west1 polls-instance
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.
```

What am I doing wrong? And more importantly how do I do it correctly?

**Addendum**

I have authenticated the Cloud SDK with `gcloud auth application-default login`. To verify:

```
$  gcloud auth list
   Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       foo@bar.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

(Real account is correct. I have redacted it here.)

Answer (score 3):

You have to [create the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance) first before you can use it. To check the list of instances you created, use:

```
gcloud sql instances list
```

Then to show information of the instance:

```
gcloud beta sql instances describe [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]
```

Substitute [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME] with the result of 'NAME' column of the `gcloud sql instances list` command.

In your case, the 403 error means you do not have permission for the 'poll' instance. Either because you do not own this instance or this instance has not yet been created.

Comment: At the time that I ran the commands in my question, I had created the Cloud SQL instance named "polls". I have since deleted it, recreated it, and deleted it again. I will recreate it another time and try the commands you describe. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `gcloud sql instances list` gave me `HTTPError 400: Project specified in the request is invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did not read the instructions closely enough:

> The connectionName value is in the format [PROJECT_NAME]:[REGION_NAME]:[INSTANCE_NAME].

This means that I need to do

```
$ gcloud config set project django-polls-184415
```

This fixes my error with the earlier `gcloud config set project` command I used. Then `gcloud sql instances describe polls` works.